# file_put_contents - ISO 8601 date in filename returns failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, file, logging

I am trying to log errors to file using `file_put_contents` method.

I have tried the following code and it works:

```
file_put_contents(date("j-n-Y G:i").'.log', $log, FILE_APPEND);
```

But i want to name a file in ISO 8601 date format, like this:

```
file_put_contents(date("c").'.log', $log, FILE_APPEND);
```

But it returns the following error:

```
failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You can't have `:` in a filename in windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens if you are using special character in file name. `date("c")` prints, for example: `2004-02-12T15:19:21+00:00`. In your case it is suggested that you use an alternative (this works for me):

```
file_put_contents(date("j-n-Y").'.log', $log, FILE_APPEND);
```

Ideal would be if you would not use special characters at all.

Comment: Yes, this would be the best way for file naming. Thanks.